# windows ubuntu/raspian python serial.read format

Tags: windows, ubuntu, raspberry-pi3, pyserial

We use pyserial library for serial port reading. I problem windows and ubuntu/raspian serial read format is different.

windows result : 0900ee00100000028d8b0900ee0010000006a9cd0900ee001000000116b90900ee0010000004bbee

ubuntu/raspian result :
09ee100050ad09ee100041a609ee1000d07309ee100040512f000f1000a06c09ee100050ad

python version : 2.7
pyserial version : 3.4

code :

```
while True:
i = seru.read()
print i.encode('hex')
```